# could not connect to server in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, command-line, ubuntu-16.04, postgresql-9.5

I am trying to connect to postgresql through command line in ubuntu but it is showing following error:-

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

For this error, I have tried many solutions from google but didn't succeeded. Can anyone help me on this issue?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+could+not+connect+to+server%3A+No+such+file+or+directory)

Answer (score 1):

You local PostgreSQL server is not running.

Comment: ALso, this is not a programming question.  There are probably better places to ask fro help.